# JPA setting parameter wrongly

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Query:

```
SELECT m.name,SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(p.end- p.begin)) / 60))                    FROM Production p 
   inner join p.machine m 
WHERE m = ?1 
  AND p.begin BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3 
  AND p.begin BETWEEN ?4 AND ?5 
group by m.name;
```

Parameters:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(jpql)
               .setParameter(1, machie)
               .setParameter(2, Timestamp.from(begin.toInstant()), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
               .setParameter(3, Timestamp.from(end.toInstant()), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
               .setParameter(4, Timestamp.from(beginHour.toInstant()), TemporalType.TIME)
               .setParameter(5, Timestamp.from(endHour.toInstant()), TemporalType.TIME);
```

The Exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "05:00:00-03"
```

How do I make the parameter be set correctly? It is setting "05:00:00-03" when the correct would be "05:00:00".

Comment: Side question: why are there 2 sets of parameters that seem to define exactly the same?

Comment: What data type is the column `begin`? And why are you passing the second (apparently useless) set of parameters as `TIME`?

Comment: The first two are for a range of dates, the following ones are for hours. Like: 
`AND p.begin BETWEEN '2017-08-20 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-30 00:00:00'
  AND p.begin BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '12:00:00'`

Comment: I'd assume `p.begin` is a timestamp as well and thus Postgres is assuming the parameters should be timestamps as well while Hibernate passes a time - hence the message "invalid input syntax for type _timestamp_". That `-03` seems to be correct for a time with timezone so it's rather a problem of telling Postgres to treat `p.begin` as a time instead of a timestamp.

Comment: `p.begin BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '12:00:00` does not make sense if `begin` is a `timestamp`. If you want to limit the range to certain dates and to a certain time span during those days you'd need something like `p.begin::date between date '2017-08-20' and date '2017-08-30' and p.begin::time between time '08:00:00' and time '12:00:00'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It could be like begin and end ranging between date and hour, and the beginHour ranging only a small period of that time range. It is for a Gantt chart, so it makes a better visualization to filter with a longer date

Comment: @Thomas Any ideas of how to workaround this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but you could try to use your own `Dialect` (e.g. a subclass of the current dialect you're using) and register your own function (e.g. `to_time`) that casts the timestamp to a time (e.g. `cast(p.begin as time)` in SQL and `to_time(p.begin)` in HQL) - have a look at the existing dialects on how to register those functions.